# Установка, настройка, запуск Phonegap

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-studio, phonegap

Потратил целый день и без результатa :(
Система:
CPU: AMD A8-5600K APU Radeon HD Graphics 3.60GHz
OS: Windows 10 64bit
Зашел на сайт Phonegap, установил node.js, установил android studio, установил phonegap.
После установки фонгапа, создаю демо проект (все по документации): phonegap create my-app
Вылетает ошибка, что нет cordova-lib.
После 2-3 часов поисков, установил более старый phonegap и проект создался.
Теперь снова по документации: phonegap run android
Вывод такой:
[phonegap] executing 'cordova run android'...
[phonegap] completed 'cordova run android'

И все!! Что делать то? Бесит, что все десятки подсказок по фонгапу 2-х летней давности...
Помогите, люди добрые!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Плюнул на phonegap и установил cordova.
Все заработало с полуклика!
Юзайте кордову!!! :)